# My stylesheet does not load when using express route optional parameter (/:id?)

Tags: javascript, css, express, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to create a simple express project that shows a food menu and the details of each option. My problem is that if I try to set an optional parameter for a route (/:id?) my stylesheet does not load.

My router:

```
router.get('/detalle/:id?', controller.details)
```

My controller:

```
const controller = {
    home: function(req,res){
        return res.render('index.ejs', {platos: platos})
    },
    details: function(req,res){
        return res.render('detalleMenu.ejs', {platos: platos})
    }
}
```

My HTML/EJS:

```
<head>
    <title>Pimienta & sal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
```

If I load `http://localhost:3000/detalle` just like that I get the css stylesheet linked to detalleMenu.ejs without a problem.
The thing is that if I try to load for example `http://localhost:3000/detalle/3` I get the detalleMenu.ejs but without the stylesheet!

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please show the HTML loading the CSS?

Comment: You're right! Thank you for that! I'm editing the main question, but here it is: 
´<head>
    <title>Pimienta & sal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>´

Comment: The css path is relative. Make it absolute. `/css/style.css` (remove the first dot.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! That was it!